# Working remotely with mysql from local centos

Tags: ssh, centos, mysql

Given the fact that Id like to connect from local machine to remote machine with ssh, and id like to be able to run mysql queries and command using local bash script that will send the commands through SSH connection, what would be the best way to approach this? the script has to be non interactive, so if I run form my local machine for example: .script.sh it will ssh (with key) to remote machine and get all the databases mysql has there? I just need steps and basic idea for this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of ways I've done this in the past

1. scp "your script" to the remote server then run it over ssh

```
ssh remote server 'bash -c "./path/to/script"'
```

2. Port forward the remote hosts mysql port of 3306 to your local host 3333

```
ssh -L 3333:remote_server_name_or_ip:3306
```

Then, run your script with sql queries and have it point to your localhost:3333